# Multi-line grep with positive and negative filtering

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep, gnome-terminal

I need to grep for a multi-line string that *doesn't* include one string, but *does* include others.  This is what I'm searching for in some HTML files:

```
<not-this>
   <this> . . . </this>
</not-this>
```

In other words, I want to find files that contain `<this>` and `</this>` on the same line, but should not be surrounded by html tags `<not-this>` on the lines before and/or after.  Here is some shorthand logic for what I want to do:

`grep 'this' && '/this' && !('not-this')`

I've seen answers with the following...

`grep -Er -C 2 '.*this.*this.*' . | grep -Ev 'not-this'`

...but this just erases the line(s) containing the "not" portion, and displays the other lines.  What I'd like is for it to not pull those results at all if "not-this" is found within a line or two of "this".

Is there a way to accomplish this?

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu and gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like an `awk` script might work better here:

```
$ cat input.txt
<not-this>
   <this>BAD! DO NOT PRINT!</this>
</not-this>

<yes-this>
   <this>YES! PRINT ME!</this>
</yes-this>


$ cat not-this.awk
BEGIN {
  notThis=0
}

/<not-this>/        {notThis=1}
/<\/not-this>/      {notThis=0}
/<this>.*<\/this>/  {if (notThis==0) print}

$ awk -f not-this.awk input.txt
   <this>YES! PRINT ME!</this>
```

Or, if you'd prefer, you can squeeze this `awk` script onto one long line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {notThis=0} /<not-this>/ {notThis=1} /<\/not-this>/ {notThis=0} /<this>.*<\/this>/ {if (notThis==0) print}' input.txt
```

Comment: You can shorten this some.  There are no need to assign `0` to a variable, and you can simplify the test like this: `awk '/<not-this>/ {notThis=1} /<\/not-this>/ {notThis=0} /<this>.*<\/this>/ && !notThis'  file`

Comment: @Jotne Thanks! I'm always interested in learning better ways to do things. I must admit I don't use `awk` enough to know more than the bare basics.